# Поиск по произвольному полю и названию

Tags: search, php, wordpress, sql

Есть одно поле ввода, и по значению из этого поля надо найти записи либо по названию, либо по кастомному полю. Если не нашлось в названиях, ищем по кастомному полю.
Помогите :(

Comment: Объясните подробней, что значит "либо по названию, либо по кастомному полю".

Comment: Это что-то типа сквозного поиска. Если не нашлось в названиях - ищем по кастомному полю. Тут отлично сработал бы оператор OR,но не знаю как его воткнуть.

Comment: Как называются стольцы в таблице?

Comment: post_title и в таблице post_meta столбец price.

Comment: И что здесь название, а что кастомное поле?
Похоже, что вы не очень хотите получить ответ. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$searchQuery = 'word';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `field1` LIKE '%{$searchQuery}%' OR `field2` LIKE '%{$searchQuery}%'"
```

В общих чертах как-то так.

**Обновление**

Открываете любой файл, смотрите там, как делаются запросы в БД, и делаете аналогично. 
$searchQuery, я так понимаю, Вы получаете из get\post, думаю, ничего страшного не будет в таком примере:

```
$searchQuery = $_GET['q'];
```

Главное не забудьте фильтровать $searchQuery, чтобы туда не вставили sql injection или еще какую дрянь.

Comment: Совсем забыл указать в самом вопросе - мне нужно сделать все это на wordpress.

Comment: Открываете любой файл, смотрите там, как делаются запросы в БД, и делаете аналогично.   
$searchQuery, я так понимаю, Вы получаете из get\post, думаю, ничего страшного не будет в таком примере:
   
    $searchQuery = $_GET['q'];

Главное не забудьте фильтровать $searchQuery, чтобы туда не вставили sql injection или еще какую дрянь.